# The most simple example of Dajaxice with Django not working

Tags: python, ajax, django, dajaxice, dajax

I have problem with the most simple example of Dajaxice. I followed the installation guide in their official http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html and the example shown here http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html or in the Github repo, it's the same https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajaxice/tree/master/examples.

When I do everything and click on the button nothing happen and in the JavaScript console there is an error that the function is undefined. I read a lot about this problem and still don't have a solution. Here is what I have. If anyone can help :(

Here is a repo with my project which is the same as the example:
https://github.com/valkirilov/dajacice-example

Comment: Please upload your settings.py file.

Comment: Here is a repo with my project: [https://github.com/valkirilov/dajacice-example](https://github.com/valkirilov/dajacice-example)

Answer (score 0):

Add `'dajaxice.finders.DajaxiceFinder',`
in

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

Comment: It's added on the bottom of the setting.py. And the case is the same, Dajaxice cannot find my functions